# Variable used on function with a dynamic value doesn't allow me to send form through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preventdefault

I have many answer forms on a page with different classes for all the forms.

all the forms got 2 buttons to send the parent form.

I send the form if `#avote_down` or `#avote_up` is clicked, then got the parent form class of the button clicked and save the class inside the var `clase`, then add the . before the class name (I know is weird the dot thing but if I don't do it, this doesn't work), after this I save the class edited before on the var called `answervotes` so we can work with it.

```
//declare variables outside the functions to use them
//inside others
var answerdata;
var answervotes;
var clase;
var clasedot;

$('#avote_down, #avote_up').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clase = $(this).parents("form:first").attr('class');
    clasedot = '.'+clase; 
    answervotes = $(clasedot);
    answerdata = answervotes.serializeArray();
    answerdata.push({name: encodeURI($(this).attr('name')), value: encodeURI($(this).attr('value'))});
    answervotes.submit();
    answerdata.pop();
});
```

if everything goes well I can send the form using the ajax function bellow, as you see the ajax function is using the vars declared before.

```
answervotes.bind('submit',function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: answervotes.attr('action'),
        type: answervotes.attr('method'),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: answerdata,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.message == "plus")
            {
                $("#avote_up").attr('class','options options-hover');
                $("#avote_down").attr('class','options');
                $("#atotal-votes").html(data.votes);
                console.log(data.votes);

            }
            if(data.message == "sub")
            {
                $("#avote_down").attr('class','options options-hover');
                $("#avote_up").attr('class','options');
                $("#atotal-votes").html(data.votes);
                console.log(data.votes);

            }
            if(data.name == "register")
            {
                $('.theme-actions').append('<div class="should-login"><span>' + data.message + '</span><div id="close"></div></div>');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.should-login').fadeOut(300);
                },4000);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.should-login').remove();
                },4300);
            }
            if(data.name == "limited_votes")
            {
                $('.theme-actions').append('<div class="should-login">    <span>' + data.message + '</span><div id="close"></div></div>');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.should-login').fadeOut(300);
                },4000);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.should-login').remove();
                },4300);
            }
            if(data.name == "repeated_vote")
            {
                $('.theme-actions').append('<div class="should-login"><span>' + data.message + '</span><div id="close"></div></div>');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.should-login').fadeOut(300);
                },4000);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.should-login').remove();
                },4300);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            console.log(data.message);
            alert("error");
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

**The problem:** When I try to send the form like this, it just send me to the form action page like if there is no e.preventDefault() method being used to prevent the normal action, but in fact it is there you see it.

**important facts:** When I assign the the value to the `answervotes` var outside the click function using a direct name like so `var answervotes = $(".parent-form1");` it works perfectly, but if I assign the name directly inside the click function, it just doesn't work either (I need this to be dynamic depending of the parent form).

**console error:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined, probably because isn't getting the `answervotes` until the button is clicked, but I suppose this would be solved with the var problem.

**here is a jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/EnmanuelDuran/cyvpkvkk/22/

Comment: you will also have to preventDefault for submitting the form

Comment: the selector $("parent-form1") will not match anything, i guess its an id so use $('#parent-form1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I nested the submit function into the click function and execute the form submit  and the following actions after executing the submit function:

```
$('#avote_down, #avote_up').on("click",function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
clase = $(this).parents("form:first").attr('class');
clasedot = '.'+clase; 
answervotes = $(clasedot);
answerdata = answervotes.serializeArray();

answervotes.bind('submit',function () {
$.ajax({
    url: answervotes.attr('action'),
    type: answervotes.attr('method'),
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: answerdata,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.message == "plus")
        {
            $("#avote_up").attr('class','options options-hover');
            $("#avote_down").attr('class','options');
            $("#atotal-votes").html(data.votes);
            console.log(data.votes);

        }
        if(data.message == "sub")
        {
            $("#avote_down").attr('class','options options-hover');
            $("#avote_up").attr('class','options');
            $("#atotal-votes").html(data.votes);
            console.log(data.votes);

        }
        if(data.name == "register")
        {
            $('.theme-actions').append('<div class="should-login"><span>' + data.message + '</span><div id="close"></div></div>');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.should-login').fadeOut(300);
            },4000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.should-login').remove();
            },4300);
        }
        if(data.name == "limited_votes")
        {
            $('.theme-actions').append('<div class="should-login">    <span>' + data.message + '</span><div id="close"></div></div>');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.should-login').fadeOut(300);
            },4000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.should-login').remove();
            },4300);
        }
        if(data.name == "repeated_vote")
        {
            $('.theme-actions').append('<div class="should-login"><span>' + data.message + '</span><div id="close"></div></div>');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.should-login').fadeOut(300);
            },4000);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.should-login').remove();
            },4300);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        console.log(data.message);
        alert("error");
    }
});
return false;
});

answerdata.push({name: encodeURI($(this).attr('name')), value: encodeURI($(this).attr('value'))});
answervotes.submit();
answerdata.pop();
});
```

it solved the basics problem, then I used unique forms classes and call the elements inside of it by using the form parent class so I can call just that element, even if they are some more ids called like that one it doesn't show problems because every form has an unique class to call the nested elements on it.

**for the record:** the variables stayed outside the functions, on the document.ready

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector for answervotes doesnt match, use console.log or alert to be sure you got the right one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var answervotes = $(".parent-form1");

    $('#avote_down, #avote_up').on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        answervotes.submit();
    });

    answervotes.on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //do ajax
    });
});
```

here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cyvpkvkk/

Comment: In fact it is not correct for my case $('#parent-form1') as an id because I'm calling the parent forms with the class name like $('.parent-form1'),if you read above I explained it before, that's why I'm using the concatenated dot(.), so it's in fact working good. I don't need preventDefault(); for the second submit function because it's already returning false for the same effect. thanks for the fast answer anyway.

Comment: in your explanaition above you used var answervotes = $("parent-form1"); so the "." is missing i just wanted to point out

Comment: and you will need the second preventDefault because the first only prevents the click bubbling for example going to an href, using  answervotes.submit(); is the same as clicking on the submit button...

Comment: I saw I missed the point on the explanation (thanks for telling me) but the code has it. if you take a view of the second code you'll see at the end a return false; which makes the same effect that preventDefault() (I already test preventDefault() many times and doesn't work either. as I said the problem is erradicating on the variable answervortes, because when I change it outside the function as I say above, the whole thing works correctly, some other ideas?, thanks for all your help, it is appreciated.

Comment: it's on a .js file on a $(document).on('ready', function() {}); block and the vars are inside of it of course.

Comment: try console.log($('.parent-form1')); within your document.ready this should output your element and proofs that the selector is correct

Comment: your console error should occur because your selector doesnt match i think

Comment: Yes I agree with you, the thing is how to make the answervotes var match inside the click function, because outside of it, it works perfectly and match.

Comment: you could assign it to a var outside like i did and then inside reuse the variable

Comment: i added a jsfiddle for you